# Javascript modal on top of Flash games, in all browsers

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, wmode

So we have a weird issue at work. We need to display a Flash game which uses the keyboard, when the game finishes, it triggers a modal popup via Javascript. We're using the wmode param set to `opaque` so that the modal displays on top of the Flash elment.

All works fine, except in IE6/7. When you press the UP or DOWN keys on the keyboard, it scrolls the page up and down, as well as sending the keyboard input to the game.

The only fix we seem to have found for this, is to remove the `classid` attribute completely from the `object` tag. But that causes the Flash element to display on top of our Javascript modal in both IE6/7.

So it seems we can only have one or the other, but not both if we wanna support IE.

Any help, hints, pointers or anything would be great, cause there's not really much available online about these kinda issues. At least not according to Google.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but you could look into binding the keyboard events in the browser (or just in IE) so they don't fire as long as the visitor is playing the game. onkeyup, onkeydown and onkeypress are the events to look at. This way you can have the object tag in there, while preventing the default scrolling behaviour.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm, that might actually be feasible. It's a little crazy, but might work... lol

Answer (score 1):

ok,
after 2 days of searching the web for the answer i've found a pure JS function that fix it in all browsers!

there you go:

```
function fix_flash() {
    // loop through every embed tag on the site
    var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embed = embeds[i];
        var new_embed;
        // everything but Firefox & Konqueror
        if (embed.outerHTML) {
            var html = embed.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")/i))
                new_embed = html.replace(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")window('|")/i, "wmode='transparent'");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_embed = html.replace(/<embed\s/i, "<embed wmode='transparent' ");
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed version
            embed.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_embed);
            embed.parentNode.removeChild(embed);
        } else {
            // cloneNode is buggy in some versions of Safari & Opera, but works fine in FF
            new_embed = embed.cloneNode(true);
            if (!new_embed.getAttribute('wmode') || new_embed.getAttribute('wmode').toLowerCase() == 'window')
                new_embed.setAttribute('wmode', 'transparent');
            embed.parentNode.replaceChild(new_embed, embed);
        }
    }
    // loop through every object tag on the site
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        object = objects[i];
        var new_object;
        // object is an IE specific tag so we can use outerHTML here
        if (object.outerHTML) {
            var html = object.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")\s*\/?\>/i))
                new_object = html.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")window('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_object = html.replace(/<\/object\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />\n</object>");
            // loop through each of the param tags
            var children = object.childNodes;
            for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                try {
                    if (children[j] != null) {
                        var theName = children[j].getAttribute('name');
                        if (theName != null && theName.match(/flashvars/i)) {
                            new_object = new_object.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")flashvars('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[^'"]*('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='flashvars' value='" + children[j].getAttribute('value') + "' />");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                }
            }
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed versiony
            object.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_object);
            object.parentNode.removeChild(object);
        }
    }
}
```

now you can just run in when the page loads with jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            fix_flash();    
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution would to be to toggle the overflow style for the body/html element on your page to *hidden*. This disables the page from scrolling, but should maintain your position on the page.

```
//toggle this on and off when showing the window
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's a good solution, cause users would have to click outside of the flash so it loses focus before they could scroll up or down on the page.